# Issue with onItemSelected

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner, android-arrayadapter

why OnItemSelected doesn't work into `array adapter`?

I have `spinner` in each row of `list view`.
this is my code:

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;

/**
 * Created by marco on 24/07/16.
 */

    public  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  {
        Spinner spinner;

        /*public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }*/

        public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
        }





            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = convertView;
                System.out.println("ciao");

                spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        getContext(),
                        R.array.country_arrays,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    /*
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    */
               /*     @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //Spinner spinner = null;
                       // String selState = (String) ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem();

                        spinner.setSelection(position);
                        String selState = (String) ( parent).getSelectedItem();
                        Toast.makeText(
                                parent.getContext(),
                                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                });*/



                return row;
            }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            spinner.setSelection(position);
            String selState = (String) ( parent).getSelectedItem();
            Toast.makeText(
                    parent.getContext(),
                    "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }


       /* @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(selState);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getContext(),
                    "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }*/

        }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Hope the list is empty. Is your listview getting displayed??

Comment: in each row of list view i see spinner, i can choose but when i choose an object, toast not appear...so method doesn't work

Comment: Is it the full code of the adapter? It is missing some important override methods like getCount().

Comment: yes, it is full code...what i missing?

Comment: The onItemSelected you are overriding is for the ListView, not the spinner. Just use the spinner's onItemSelected?

Comment: yes, i use onItemSelected into array adapter so for spinner...i must use it for list view?

Comment: @Skyler so how i must write my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in your OnItemSelected method....

Change

```
 String selState = (String) ( parent).getSelectedItem();
```

to

```
 String selState = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: can you help me,please ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in getView method, not onItemSelected method. Your onItemSelected method is for listview.

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        String selState = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(
                parent.getContext(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

});
```

Comment: doesn't work......